# Root directory resetting in Google Cloud Shell

Tags: apt, google-cloud-shell

When I try to install an apt package in the Cloud Shell, I install it and it works fine. Next time I open the Cloud Shell, it is not there. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cloud Shell documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works):

> When you start Cloud Shell, it provisions a Compute Engine virtual machine running a Debian-based Linux operating system. Cloud Shell instances are provisioned on a per-user, per-session basis. The instance persists while your Cloud Shell session is active; after an hour of inactivity, your session terminates and its VM is discarded. For more information about those limitations you can check the [Cloud Shell usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits).

This means that Cloud Shell is only intended to interact with the Google Cloud Platform on a temporary basis during a limited time.

In case you want to configure a shell environment the right product to use would be a Compute Engine instance. Here is a [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux) that shows how to create a Linux virtual machine (VM) instance in Compute Engine.

Answer (score 0):

While a Cloud Shell environment is [ephemeral](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#custom_installed_software_packages_and_persistence) (i.e., it gets torn down after session end), your Cloud Shell home directory is persistent.  You can add a [customization script](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/configuring-cloud-shell#environment_customization) to your home directory to reconfigure your environment when Cloud Shell starts.